# Query materialized view returned more data than local table

Tags: clickhouse

When I query one materialized view, I got more data then the local table it based on.
What's wrong with it?

Query mv search_uv_minute_level:

```
    toYYYYMMDD(stime) AS dt, 
    uniqExactMerge(imp_uv) AS imp_uv, 
    uniqExactMerge(clk_uv) AS clk_uv, 
    uniqExactMerge(imp_count) AS imp_count, 
    sumMerge(clk_count) AS clk_count
FROM search_uv_minute_level
WHERE (toYYYYMMDD(stime) = 20210623) AND (toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(stime) >= 20210623150500) AND (toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(stime) <= 20210623150800)
GROUP BY toYYYYMMDD(stime)

┌───────dt─┬─imp_uv─┬─clk_uv─┬─imp_count─┬─clk_count─┐
│ 20210623 │ 114108 │  66320 │    179590 │    110870 │
└──────────┴────────┴────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Query local table search_action_dwd:

```
SELECT 
    toYYYYMMDD(dt) AS t, 
    uniqExact(IF(type = 'IMP', uid, NULL)) AS uv, 
    uniqExact(IF(type = 'CLK', uid, NULL)) AS clk_uv, 
    uniqExact(IF(type = 'IMP', e, NULL)) AS imp, 
    SUM(IF(type = 'CLK', 1, 0)) AS clk
FROM search_action_dwd
WHERE (toYYYYMMDD(dt) = 20210623) AND (toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(dt) >= 20210623150500) AND (toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(dt) <= 20210623150800)
GROUP BY t

┌────────t─┬────uv─┬─clk_uv─┬────imp─┬───clk─┐
│ 20210623 │ 92755 │  54265 │ 141838 │ 87337 │
└──────────┴───────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

mv definition:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW qiso_bi.search_uv_minute_level (`stime` DateTime('Asia/Shanghai'), `imp_uv` AggregateFunction(uniqExact, String), `clk_uv` AggregateFunction(uniqExact, String), `imp_count` AggregateFunction(uniqExact, String), `clk_count` AggregateFunction(sum, UInt8)) ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{cluster}/{shard}/search_uv_minute_level', '{replica}') PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(stime) ORDER BY toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(stime) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192 AS SELECT toStartOfMinute(dt) AS stime, uniqExactState(IF(type = 'IMP', uid, NULL)) AS imp_uv, uniqExactState(IF(type = 'CLK', uid, NULL)) AS clk_uv, uniqExactState(IF(type = 'IMP', e, NULL)) AS imp_count, sumState(IF(type = 'CLK', 1, 0)) AS clk_count FROM search_action_dwd WHERE toYYYYMMDD(dt) >= 20210623 GROUP BY toStartOfMinute(dt)
```

Comment: Such function  AggregateFunction(uniqExact -- uniqExact always slower with MatView than original table. Try uniq or uniqHLL12

Comment: What is the engine of search_action_dwd? ReplacingMT ?

Comment: Hi @DennyCrane . It is ReplicatedMergeTree.

Comment: Then something wrong with your setup or insertion. Do you have reproducible example?